# SQLiteDatabase transaction doesn't add data

Tags: android, android-sqlite, sqlite

I have to execute a bunch of SQL rows in order to put some data into my tables. There's a lot of those rows (around 15 MB of raw SQL instructions), so I tried to use transactions in order to improve database performance. That's my code:

```
SQLiteDatabase db;
...
db.beginTransaction();
...
//in cycle:
db.execSQL(row);
...
db.endTransaction();
db.close();
```

But when I launch my app, I can see in logs that SQL scripts are executing, but there's no data in DB. And if I simply remove `db.beginTransaction();` and `db.endTransaction();` - everything works fine. Any ideas how I have to work with transactions?

Comment: Call db.setTransactionSuccessful(); after execSql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
db.beginTransaction();
try {
    //in cycle:
    db.execSQL(row);
    db.setTransactionSuccessful();

}catch {

}finally {
        db.endTransaction();

}
```

> public void setTransactionSuccessful ()
>
> Added in API level 1 Marks the current transaction as successful. Do
>   not do any more database work between calling this and calling
>   endTransaction. Do as little non-database work as possible in that
>   situation too. If any errors are encountered between this and
>   endTransaction the transaction will still be committed.

Comment: I will read the whole documentation page.
I will read the whole documentation page.
I will read the whole documentation page.
I will read the whole documentation page.
Thank you.